# How can i initialize server as client just one time in react native?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, tcpsocket

```
render(){
    const { wifi } = this.state;
    /*const client = TcpSocket.createConnection({
        port: 80,
        host: '192.168.4.100',
        tls: false,
        interface: 'wifi',
        //localAddress: '192.168.4.101',
    }, () => {
        client.write('APPSETTING CONNECTED');
        
    });*/
```

I put this code in render, so it results to multi connection by same IP.
How can i initialize this server as client just one time in react native?

Comment: put it in componentDidMount instead

Comment: Or crate a singleton.

Comment: Can i have some example source codes? How can i declare client variable as global?